# how to send mail using phpmailer (laravel);

Tags: php, laravel, phpmailer

I want to send email verification link to users after registration using phpmailer(laravel). everything was working fine a couple of days ago but it has stop working now. i really cant tell what is wrong. it always give me the email error('Sorry something went wrong we could not send you an email verification link')

mail_handler.php

```
 <?php
session_start();
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);


require_once 'config.php';
$user = new Auth();

if (isset($_POST['action'])&& $_POST['action']=='register'){
    $name = $user->test_input($_POST['name']);
    $email = $user->test_input($_POST['email']);
    $pass = $user->test_input($_POST['password']);



    $hpass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    if ($user->user_exist($email)) {
        echo $user->showMessage('warning', 'This Index number is already registered!');
    }
    else{
        if ($user->register($name,$email,$hpass,$email)) {
            echo'';
            $SESSION['user']= $email;
            try{
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username   = Database::USERNAME;                     // SMTP username
                $mail->Password   = Database::PASSWORD;                               // SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
                $mail->Port       = 587; 
        
                //Recipients
                $mail->setFrom(Database::USERNAME,'ENSapp');
                $mail->addAddress($email); 
        
                 // Content
                $mail->isHTML(true);  
                $mail->Subject = 'E-mail Verification';
                $mail->Body    = '<h3>Click the below link to verify your E-Mail.<br><a
                href="http://localhost/admin/verify-email.php?email='.$email.'">
                href="http://localhost/admin/verify-email.php?email='.$email.'
                </a><br>Regards<br> Executives!</h3>'; 
                
                $mail->send();
                echo $user->showMessage('success','Registration succefull we have sent you an E-Mail verification link. <strong>Please Sign In and check your e-mail to verify now!</strong>');
               
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                echo $user->showMessage('info','Sorry something went wrong we could not send you an email verification link');
             
            }
        
          
        }
        else{
            echo $user->showMessage('danger','Something went wrong! Please try again later! ');
        }
    }
}

  
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
class Database {
    const USERNAME = 'example@gmail.com';
    const PASSWORD = '*******';
    

    // Checking Input 
    public function test_input($data){
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    // Error success message alert
    public function showMessage($type,$message){
        return '<div class="alert alert-'.$type.' alert-dismissible "> 
                    <button type="button" class="close" 
                    data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong class="text-center"> '.$message.' </strong>
                    
                     </div>';
    }

    

?>
```

Comment: I expect `$e` would probably give you some details about that, wouldn't it?

Comment: Why not print `$e->getMessage()` after all thats why the exception is there to let you know what went wrong. Stuff you make up for yourself is normally less useful

Comment: This really doesn't look like Laravel code. Laravel has [its own mailer interface](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail) which works fine, so in a Laravel context I'd recommend sticking with it.

Answer (score 1):

Never send a html form in the email.
Instead you can generate a 6 digit random number and send it in that email and also save this number in a session.
when the user enter this code to verify his account , you can compare the code he enter with the value stored in the session.

Also: have you turned "less secure app access" to on??

Comment: Yeah I have turned  on "less secure app access" pertaining to the generation of 6 digit random number and send in to email how do i go about that

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you said.

Comment: if you please can you tell me what you want clearly?? because I did not understand what you wanted